How to add a custom init process to initramfs image built with Dracut?
I want to use Dracut for initramfs image creation. This image should be able to shrink a root filesystem on a Fedora machine. I would like to test partition shrinking flow manually first. If everything is okay, I will replace these commands with a script to do shrinking automatically in non-interactive mode on a remote machine.
I was able to add the 'parted' and 'resize2fs' tools that I needed for this task. However, the image still uses 'systemd' as the init process and just boots the main Fedora installation. So I need to boot into some kind of shell and run the 'parted' and 'resize2fs' commands by hand.
My attempt to add a simple 'init' script to the initramfs image failed (I put it as '/sbin/init' and turned the execution bit on. But the kernel complains that it can't find a runnable init process).
So my question my question is: how to add your own init process to an initramfs image with Dracut?

hm, when using a fedora userland, wouldn't you want systemd to walk through all the steps of setting up LVM/dm/…, detection of USB-connected hardware etc? As far as I understand your problem, you'd probably just want to remove the "switching root" step (because there's no new filesystem root you'd want to switch to), and replace the default multiuser target with a drop to a login shell?

@MarcusMüller, maybe, my approach in the description is incorrect indeed. I would be happy if the task could be solved with systemd tools already inside the initramfs image. I can make changes to some of the systemd service files and add them to the initramfs image, right?

yes! As a matter of fact, when you run journalctl -b and look for Starting initrd-switch-root.service: Everything before are services defined by files within the initrd!

@MarcusMüller, exactly! During one of the attempts, the last error in the 'journalctl' command output was about 'systemd' being unable to run this service due to an incorrect root set. So I can replace 'initrd-switch...' service file with my own?

@MarcusMüller, just want to be precise: my main task is to shrink the root filesystem partition to add other ones. I saw here someone's proposal to do it in runtime by creating tmpfs filesystem and run 'pivot_root' to it. But I failed on the stage of stopping all systemd services to be able to unmount root filesystem before shrinking it.

I can see how that can fail in a fully running system. You'd basically would "unboot" to a very early stage of your system for that.
